# Undo update-alternatives

Tags: gcc, update-alternatives

I had to run the command `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 20`, but unfortunately I misstyped and wrote `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gccc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 20` (so gccc instead of gcc).

Now, when trying to run the regular command, it tells me the alternative link /usr/bin/gcc is allready managed by gcccc.

I've searched around but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gccc`.

Comment: If you're using this method to, say, fix a botched `python` or `php` alternative, you'll need to restore an alternative with `--set` or `--install` after removal. As you'd expect, `--remova-all`, disconnects all links to whatever package you're working with, leaving you with none in your `PATH`.

Comment: I also had to do `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 3` and `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7` to restore my 19.04 system back to what it was (I hope).

Answer (score 4):

```
update-alternatives --remove gccc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8
```

is the answer you seek.